# Datalab - can't connect to instance after modifying startup.sh

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I'm working on Datalab and I need specific versions of plotly and scikit-learn.
I followed [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/adding-libraries#adding_python_libraries_to_a_cloud_datalab_instance) and modified `/content/datalab/.config/startup.sh` which is now as follows:

```
pip install plotly==4.1.0
pip install scikit-learn==0.21.3
```

If I remove the second line (scikit-learn) I'm able to connect to datalab but the required version of plotly is not installed.

Comment: Have you tried running the following ```%%bash
echo "pip install plotly==4.1.0" >> /content/datalab/.config/startup.sh
echo "pip install scikit-learn==0.21.3" >> /content/datalab/.config/startup.sh
cat /content/datalab/.config/startup.sh``` in a cell and then restarting the Datalab instance as explained in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/adding-libraries#adding_python_libraries_to_a_cloud_datalab_instance)?

Comment: @bhito yes, but the procedure to restart the server didn't work so I manually stopped and restarted the instance